# Splitting String which can contains delimeter

Tags: java, split, passwords

Now I have:

```
for (String userPass : splitted) {
        String user = userPass.split("=")[0];
        String pass = userPass.split("=")[1];
        config.put(user, pass);
    }
```

which works for file which contains e.g

`service1.password=dsjahdsahjk!sdafds`

but as the second part is password it can also be:

`service1.password=das-=asdwe=12f=`

then my idea will fail miserably. What is the best approach to ensure that I am splitting by `=` but not this one which is inside password?

Comment: Get the index of the first equal sign and extract the substrings before and after the equal sign?

Comment: You can add a limit parameter to the split method `userPass.split("=", 2);` The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can just try the following and add an additional parameter `limit` to your split method:

```
String pass = userPass.split("=", 2)[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substring`.

```java
for (String userPass : splitted) {
    int firstEqualIndex = userPass.indexOf("=");
    String user = userPass.substring(0, firstEqualIndex);
    String pass = userPass.substring(firstEqualIndex + 1);
    config.put(user, pass);
}
```

`indexOf` always returns the first occurrence. So it will work even if you have multiple `=` in the password.

Answer (score 0):

You've essentially got a one-property properties file there:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.io.Reader;

public class Prop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Reader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of(args[0]))) {
            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.load(in);
            System.out.println(p.get("service1.password"));
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output: das-=asdwe=12f= is correct

Comment: Didn't mention in question but I have there many more properties. It's not just one.